# How to add a BarLegend to a ListLinePlot?

Tags: legending, plotting

I'm trying to add a color `BarLegend` to a `ListLinePlot` with multiple lists.  With 20+ lists a normal Legend gets long and bulky.  Basically, each list line is associated with a different value.  I've created a color gradient for the lines using the Hue function but cannot figure out how to get `BarLegend` to work with `ListLinePlot`.  I've included a sample of the plot I have so far.  It would be a much cleaner presentation with a colorbar for the legend.  How do I do this, in an elegant way?  I'd even settle for a non-elegant method right now.  [image: example of what I have]

Comment: You should be able to use `Epilog` (or `Prolog`) and `Inset`.  Have you already created a `BarLegend` you want to use?

Comment: I'm about to go to bed, so I can't give a full answer. But, you want `PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{colorFunction, {xmin, xmax}}]` as the option. To place it within the plot, wrap `BarLegend` in `Placed`.

Answer (score 3):

```
ListLinePlot[Table[Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 250]], {10}], 
             PlotStyle -> (Hue[#] & /@ Range[0., .9, .1]), 
             ImageSize -> 500, 
             PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Hue, {0, 10}}, 10, ColorFunctionScaling -> True]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This worked perfectly.

Comment: @madscientist, glad I could help. Welcome to mma.se.